# Data move from table to table , column type error

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, timescaledb

I'm using Postgresql with timescaledb extension, pg13 - tsdb 2.2.1

table 1

```
create table user 
(
    ...
    join_dt timestamptz NULL,
    ...
);
```

Table 2

```
create table a_user
( 
    ...
    join_dt timestamptz NULL,
    ...
);
```

I used SQL insert to a_user table so there's data inside the table, and want to move the data to user table by querying this :

```
insert into user 
    select * from a_user;
```

I get this error:

> [42804] ERROR: column "join_dt" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type character varying

The original data comes from a table which is like this

```
create table ori_user
(
    ...
    join_dt timestamp(6) with time zone,
    ...
);
```

I export data as SQL insert form from ori_user, and then inserted into a_user, and now I want to move from a_user to user.

This is what I have tried:

```
insert into user select 
...
join_dt::timestamptz,
...
from a_user;
```

does not work.

```
with aa as (select  pg_typeof(join_dt)::varchar as type,*  from a_user)
select * from aa where aa.type not like 'timestamp with time zone';
```

shows no row.

any other solutions? please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely the column orders do not match. It's good coding practice to always specify the target tables: `insert into "user" (col1, col2,  join_dt) select col1, col2, join_dt  from a_user`

Comment: oh my god why did I not think of it.... they were supposed to be exactly same so I guessed they are same, but now I found out columns are in different order. I feel so foolish.. thank you for pointing out my mistake.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought table columns are in same order, but it wasn't.

fix the order, problem solved.